# Getting an error when using concatenate in PowerBI

Tags: string, concatenation, powerbi, dax

Just as the title says, Concatenate doesn't work.
It works if I type: = "Hello "&"World"

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: You are trying to use DAX in the Power Query Editor. Power Query does not use DAX but a language called m. `= CONCATENATE("Hello ", "World")` translated to m is `= Text.Combine({"Hello ", "World"})`

Answer (score 0):

Marco Vos, Thank you very much. Newbie here...

"You are trying to use DAX in the Power Query Editor. Power Query does not use DAX but a language called m. = CONCATENATE("Hello ", "World") translated to m is = Text.Combine({"Hello ", "World"}) – Marco Vos 4"